# Content AB testing in Sitecore

Tags: content-testing

I am using Sitecore 8.1.
I wanted to understand about Statistics generated when AB testing is started. I started Content based AB testing on one of webpage.I have not involved goals to my test. The Test Result which I see is as below:

[image]

[image: TestResult2]

[image: ActiveTest]

As seen in the Active Tests pop-up it gives me Effect as **12.63%**. So I wanted to know what does effect mean here.

Also I have no clue how many visitors are hitting/getting exposed to my Variation 1 and how many to variation 2. Is there anywhere I can look for this?

If you all could suggest any good reads explaining about AB testing. On web I could find links on how to start AB test but nothing regarding where and how I can validate my test. Or how Sitecore does AB test behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Goals are critical to measuring the performance of tests since Sitecore measures content effectiveness of test variations based on value delivered, not just clicks through.

As for the effect, I believe that % is the effect that the test had on the overall engagement value generated on the website - so if you have goals elsewhere on the site it is calculating based on when a user sees a test variation and takes an action/triggers a goal somewhere else in the experience.

To see the variations (im not sure if this is right), you should view the test in experience editor and see if it gives you that information there?